# Locating and validating a specific user ID from .txt file for c++

Tags: c++

I was unsure on how to read specific points of information on reading a text file. What I am trying to do is.

1. Get user ID from their input (cin >> userID)
2. Program checks for ID if it exists in the database (read .txt file)
3. If ID exists, proceed to next portion
4. Else, cout error Message

   `//Example text from the file:`

   `12345678
   23456789
   34567890
   45678901
   etc. 
   etc.
   etc.`

Here, if user entered "12345678", I want to learn how I would allow c++ to only specifically scan 12345678 in the .txt file. Therefore generating a  "*Identification Verified.*" message. Or can someone generous direct me to a proper link?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/  which shows you how to open a file and loop over the lines in it. You want to loop over the lines until you find one that matched the input userID.

Comment: Your suggestion seemed the best to work with! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use std::string::find.

Example:

```
if (fullString.find(partOfString) != std::string::npos) {
    std::cout << "found!" << endl;
}
```

So in your example, the line of the text document you're on will be the `fullString` and the userID entered will be the partOfString. You could also just do a direct comparison with something like

```
if (userString == lineFromFile)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Your first example would match "345" to "12345678", no? This probably isn't what is wanted. std::string::compare is probably a better option (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)

Answer (score 0):

"Specifically scan 123456 in the .txt file" - you can't.  What you have is a text file, not a database.  If your file is very big, I would argue that the solution would be to use a database (eg sqlite) and let that generate an index for you.  You can then query the database for any userIds matching xyz.

Comment: This answer misleading. If you have a text file with one ID per line, of course you can scan it just by iterating over the lines and checking if they match the ID you're looking for. Of course a proper database may be a better solution, but may be overkill for OP's purposes.

Comment: Not misleading at all, since the OP has explicitly said they want to scan just the one line they're interested in - well, that's just not possible, and if it was then you'd make a market leading database.

Comment: Perhaps OP can clarify - I think their overall aim is just to check whether ID exists in the file. But yes, as you say it's not possible to do that without reading all of the file (up until a matching line is found, if any). The question was about how to read and parse a text file though, so a better answer would be to give some hints on how to do that and what the limitations are, rather than just saying "you can't"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know how to [open the file using fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) and whatnot, you could do something like a while loop.

```
ifstream yourFile;
int userID, wantedID;
bool found = false;

//open file
while(yourFile >> userID && found == false){ //this says while there is numbers that can be put into UIN, do this. This way it won't keep trying after it has run out of numbers, and will also stop if/when it is found, whichever comes first.
    if(UserID == wantedID){
        found = true;
    }
 }
```

So what this will allow to do is search the entire file for the ID, and when it's found stop searching. You can then do what you wish with it, though you would also most likely still want to check the found boolean when working with the userID, in case it wasn't found and ran out of numbers.